# Spring Boot Jasper Report Blank PDF

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jasper-reports

I have an web application. I use Spring Boot 1.3.3, AngularJS, and Jasper 5.6.0. When i try to download jasper report, i get blank PDF page. My code is:

```
String jasperAdi = "yillikPlan.jasper";
StringBuffer pathMain = new StringBuffer();
pathMain.append(this.getClass().getResource("/static/jasper").getPath());
String jasperFileName = pathMain.toString() + File.separator + jasperAdi;
File jasperFile = new File(jasperFileName);
JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(jasperFile);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, param, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(ckModelList));
if (jasperPrint != null) {
    byte[] pdfReport = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData("yillikPlan.pdf", "yillikPlan.pdf");
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> respon = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(pdfReport, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return respon;

}
```

**My jasper file location is /static/jasper. ckModelList is a java.util.List. param is a Hashmap which i push report parameters.**

How i fix this problem.

[image: Blank Jasper Report]

Comment: Did you try to debug? Is the datasource ok?

Comment: Yes i try debug. My datasource is ok. @AlexK

Comment: I face the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @tranceholic no i didn't solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I was with the same issue when I tried to start using jasper in my Spring Boot application but it had nothing wrong with my java code it was just the propertie 'When no Data type' of the report. I was just testing, therefore I don't have any data only a label it took some hours to realize it.

If you have any problem understanding my "improving" english, please let me know that I'll try to explain better.

[Report Properties Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bisgM.png)